# Bones don't attach to lower half of the body

Tags: rigging

I've been trying taking the next step in my blender journey by dipping my toes into rigging for quite some time now, the results weren't the best

For some reason, while the upper half of the body attached with no problems, the lower half refuses to attach no matter what i do, here's a gif that shows the problem quite clearly

[image: A basic human model being pulled down by the waist, the knees, instead of bending, shrink, making the model look like a dwarf]

I am following a really basic tutorial, and i watched it several times seeing where i could've been wrong, without much to find, i don't know what to do

Here's the file, be aware that i'm really new to all of this, and the bones and such are in spanish, if you need it translated, ask me and i'll add the translations
[pasteall.org/blend/3a6ce5db73b74e84bfceb70c0c862253](https://pasteall.org/blend/3a6ce5db73b74e84bfceb70c0c862253)

Comment: Please upload your blend file and paste the link into your question so that we can have a look: https://pasteall.org/blend/. First thought though is that the origins of your armature and object aren't in the same place. Also make sure that the scale is applied to both the object and armature in Object mode with CTRL-A > Scale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All bones of your legs have their "Deform" option unchecked, so they don't act (and they don't even create a vertex group during automatic weight function).

Check them as deforming, uncheck this option for pole bones and IK target bones.

To complete the fix, select the character, press Alt P (clear parent and keep transformations), then Shift select the rig and press Ctrl P (with automatic weight).

[image]